# imshow in C++, toolbar disappeared

Tags: c++, image, opencv, display, imshow

I have been using the same code to show a matrix image in my Ubuntu system, but recently, out of the blue, the display window automatically changed and is now not functioning properly.

For starters, the toolbar that should be there on the display window had disappeared, So I can't save the image using the GUI, and secondly, I can no longer scroll to zoom into the image.

```
Mat dataMatrix1(2048,2048,CV_8UC1, m);
imshow("Display window", dataMatrix1 );
waitKey(10);
```

Both these features were there yesterday, does anyone have any idea, what's going on?

You can see in the snapshot that there is no toolbar!

[image: Screen snapshot here]

Comment: Did you update OpenCV (or or something like Qt, or GTK)? IIRC the toolbar is available only when OpenCV was built using the Qt backend.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there was no update.

Comment: I checked my update log, any of these seem to be suspicious? libfluidsynth1, libsdl-mixer1.2, libsdl-ttf2.0-0, libmpeg0, musescore-soundfont-gm, libportmidi0, python-pygame, libmikmod2

Comment: Not really. Odd. | Just for posterity, please [edit] your question and add info about what exact version of OpenCV are you using, and how did you obtain it.

Answer (score 1):

The toolbar is only present if you have OpenCV installed with a QT GUI backend (doesn't work with GTK). There are two ways to install with QT backend -

1. Build from source using cmake and specify WITH_QT=ON (this is the long and hard method).
2. The easier one and the one that worked for me - create a new virtual environment with Conda and type in `conda install -c menpo opencv` in terminal. Try running the code and if the issue still persists, type in the following command - `pip install --upgrade pip` followed by `pip install opencv-contrib-python`